# Issue with Hue File browser

Tags: hadoop, hue

I install a hue web client on my hadoop 2.5.1 cluster, hive web ui in HUE running well, but when I click the filebrowser button I find this error on my log.

> Processing exception: Cannot access: /user/hadoop.  Note: You are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser (which is "hadoop").: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/hadoop/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
>       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/home/hadoop/hue/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py", line 104, in index
>       return view(request, path)
>     File "/home/hadoop/hue/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py", line 181, in view
>       raise PopupException(msg , detail=e)
>   PopupException: Cannot access: /user/hadoop.  Note: You are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser (which is "hadoop").

I can't touch the hdfs with hue, has anyone else experienced this and determined the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

in core-site.xml set

```
hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups =*
hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts =*
```

In hdfs-Site.xml / or you can give permission to hue user of dir  /

```
dfs.permissions.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

That's right ! Either use username as "hadoop" to login to Hue or give permissions to Hue user on the HDFS.

Comment: Yes, very probably need to chmod /user/hadoop to readable for the 'hadoop' user

Comment: You might want to provide the solution for others, or accept the one already given :-)

Answer (score 1):

We also need to add the user name in Hdfs to solve this issue. Try running these commands in your terminal

Considering x as your user name

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/x/
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown x:x /user/x/
```